# How to find one frame of encoded sample using MediaMuxer?

Tags: android, mp4, h.264, mediamuxer

I'm implementing converter h264 to mp4. I have posted question overflow a day ago. I was advised by following comment.

```
 * while(!finished) {
 *   // getInputBuffer() will fill the inputBuffer with one frame of encoded
 *   // sample from either MediaCodec or MediaExtractor, set isAudioSample to
 *   // true when the sample is audio data, set up all the fields of bufferInfo,
 *   // and return true if there are no more samples.
 *   finished = getInputBuffer(inputBuffer, isAudioSample, bufferInfo);
 *   if (!finished) {
 *     int currentTrackIndex = isAudioSample ? audioTrackIndex : videoTrackIndex;
 *     muxer.writeSampleData(currentTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);
 *   }
 * };
```

Thus, I implemented some code to find the encoded frames. This code is very long, I contains maximum codes for having much infomation. In advance, I apologize you.

```
        MediaFormat videoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
//        videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar);
//        videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000);

        videoFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x67, 0x42, 0x00, 0x1F, (byte)0x9D, (byte)0xB8, 0x14, 0x01, 0x6E, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0x80,
                (byte)0x80, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x81}));
        videoFormat.setByteBuffer("csd-1", ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {
                0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x68, (byte)0xCE, 0x3C, (byte)0x80 }));
        videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 25);
        videoFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 12);
        int videoTrackIndex = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat);
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(500000);
        boolean finished = false;
        String videofilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "video.h264";
        File videoinputFile = new File(videofilePath);
        FileInputStream videoFis = null;
        try {
            videoFis = new FileInputStream(videoinputFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        muxer.start();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024 * 1024 * 15);
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1000000];
        bb.mark();
        // read all
        while(true) {
            try {
                int bb2 = videoFis.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                if(bb2 != -1) {
                    bb.put(tempBuffer, 0, bb2);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        bb.reset();

        // to find 00 00 00 01 sequence.
        int mata[][] = new int[5][256];
        mata[0][0] = 1;
        mata[1][0] = 2;
        mata[2][0] = 3;
        mata[3][1] = 4;
        int step = 0;
        // find first key frame.
        while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
            step = mata[step][(bb.get() & 0xFF)];
            if(step < 4) {
                step = mata[step][(bb.get() & 0xFF)];
            }
            else if(step == 4) {
                byte g = bb.get();
                if((g & 0x1f) == 5) {
                    bb.position(bb.position() - 5);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        step = 0;
        int frameIndex = 0;
        while(!finished) {
            int nextPosition = -1;
            int offset = bb.position();
            bb.get(); bb.get(); bb.get(); bb.get();
            byte nalUnit = bb.get();
            while(bb.hasRemaining()) {
                if(step < 4) {
                    step = mata[step][(bb.get() & 0xFF)];
                }
                else if(step == 4) {
                    byte g = bb.get();
                    if((g & 0x60) == 0x60) {
                        nextPosition = bb.position() - 5;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(nextPosition == -1)
                break;
            step = 0;
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            bufferInfo.flags = (nalUnit & 0x1f) == 5 ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME : 0;
            bufferInfo.offset = offset;
            bufferInfo.size = nextPosition - offset;
            bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = 0 + (frameIndex++) * 1000 * 1000 / 25;
            Log.d(",,", "NAL header: " + String.format("%02X", nalUnit) + "...offset: " + bufferInfo.offset + "...size: " + bufferInfo.size + "..." + "pts: " + bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs);
            muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);
            bb.position(nextPosition);
        }
        muxer.stop();
        muxer.release();
```

I got the messages

```
02-24 09:53:03.432 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 65...offset: 220159...size: 64780...pts: 137
02-24 09:53:03.432 12327-12410/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg I/MPEG4Writer: setStartTimestampUs: 137
    Earliest track starting time: 137
02-24 09:53:03.433 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 284939...size: 10531...pts: 40137
02-24 09:53:03.434 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 295470...size: 15908...pts: 80137
    NAL header: 61...offset: 311378...size: 20194...pts: 120137
02-24 09:53:03.435 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 331572...size: 20628...pts: 160137
02-24 09:53:03.436 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 352200...size: 21346...pts: 200137
02-24 09:53:03.437 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 373546...size: 21407...pts: 240137
    NAL header: 61...offset: 394953...size: 22494...pts: 280137
02-24 09:53:03.438 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 417447...size: 23230...pts: 320137
02-24 09:53:03.439 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 440677...size: 23820...pts: 360137
02-24 09:53:03.440 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 464497...size: 24298...pts: 400137
02-24 09:53:03.441 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/,,: NAL header: 61...offset: 488795...size: 24424...pts: 440137
02-24 09:53:03.441 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-24 09:53:03.442 12327-12327/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg, PID: 12327
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bufferInfo must specify a valid buffer offset, size and presentation time
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
```

We have a raw h.264 file known gopsize = 12. A java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error occurs when loop counter is 12.

Also I attched my h264 file's NAL header infomation. (command: xxd -p Downloads/video.h264 | grep "00000001", link: https://ideone.com/g0TRC9)

**Update**

I modified buffer size to enough to big. But my code is still not worked. And I continuesly googled it and modified following codes.

```
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int rNalUnit = (nalUnit & 0x1f);
            Log.d(",,", String.format("nal value: %d", rNalUnit));
            bufferInfo.flags = (nalUnit & 0x1f) == 5 ? MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_KEY_FRAME : 0;
            bufferInfo.offset = offset;
            bufferInfo.size = nextPosition - offset;
            writeSize += bufferInfo.size;
            bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = 137 + (frameIndex++) * 1000 * 1000 / 25;
            inputBuffer.mark();
            inputBuffer.position(bufferInfo.offset);
            int oldLimit = inputBuffer.limit();
            inputBuffer.limit(bufferInfo.offset + bufferInfo.size);
            muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrackIndex, inputBuffer, bufferInfo);
            inputBuffer.reset();
            inputBuffer.limit(oldLimit);
```

Finally I succeed to build mp4 without any MediaMuxer's exceptions. And I got the messages.

```
02-25 20:48:27.263 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/TAG: 9293824...9293824
02-25 20:48:27.263 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg I/MPEG4Writer: Normal stop process
02-25 20:48:27.263 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping. Stop source
    Video track source stopping
    Video track source stopped
02-25 20:48:27.263 3555-3649/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg I/MPEG4Writer: Received total/0-length (463/0) buffers and encoded 463 frames. - Video
02-25 20:48:27.263 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopped. Stop source
    Stopping writer thread
02-25 20:48:27.266 3555-3648/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/MPEG4Writer: 0 chunks are written in the last batch
02-25 20:48:27.266 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/MPEG4Writer: Writer thread stopped
02-25 20:48:27.268 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg I/MPEG4Writer: The mp4 file will not be streamable.
02-25 20:48:27.268 3555-3555/com.example.ksoo.ballbotpkg D/MPEG4Writer: Video track stopping. Stop source
```

[image]

See above picture. mp4 file I made has enough blocks, but VLC player can't render any pictures. I think mp4 has not any h.264 key frame. My mp4 builder repo is: https://github.com/hsnks100/mp4builder

Comment: You are reading past the end of `inputBuffer`, which only contains 500000 bytes. 488795 + 24424 > 500000. Also, you should seriously consider putting some data into `inputBuffer` :)

Comment: Thank you, @greeble31. I updated my answer.

Comment: Why don't you use `xxd` to check the file you've made. Probably see a lot of 0's in it, right? You are not putting anything into `inputBuffer`. I recommend you study a lot of `ByteBuffer` examples so you can understand how it works. Then, use the debugger to examine the state of `inputBuffer` at the moment of the `writeSampleData()` call, and verify, for yourself, that it is in a valid state.

Comment: ```xxd compressed.mp4 | head                                                                                                                                                                             
00000000: 0000 0018 6674 7970 6d70 3432 0000 0000  ....ftypmp42....
00000010: 6973 6f6d 6d70 3432 3f3f 3f3f 6d64 6174  isommp42????mdat
00000020: 0002 eba5 65b8 4862 c003 3815 f8a7 3942  ....e.Hb..8...9B
```
I think I insert valid parameters, but it doesn't work. anyway, thank you. I will try to study ByteBuffer more.